# How to make a Card dependent on (or contingent) on a List on a different Boards in Trello

Tags: trello, trello-organization

We are using Trello for Development.

I have Boards for:

- Bugs
- Implementing features
- UX Design
- Website

Often, I'll have Cards in one Board (UX or Website) that should be worked on when (are contingent) on a version Release List on the Implement... board.

Solutions I've considered:

- Having a Card on the Release List that basically says "do this other thing", but you can't link a Card to a List. :(
- Putting the Cards on the Implement Features Board in the appropriate release List and including a note in the title (UX, WEBSITE, etc.)
- **Current solution**  I duplicate some Release Lists in the other Boards. This is klunky and error prone.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I have several boards that are dependent on each other, respectively, I have one project board with task and work packages and sub-boards with the more granular tasks.

How I navigate between boards, respectively link resources, notably cards, from other boards is that I use the board's URL in the description or comments of dependent cards.

While this does not provide a hard dependency which would lead to the ability to check constraints, noting your dependencies in comments or even checklists, which I find very nifty by the way, is a feature that could solve your issue. I included an example below.

[image]

Task 7.1. is on this board as you can see while Task 7.2 resides on another board. The links are navigable and merely references meaning that they are updated should you change cards, including the title.